# Undo the last update in SQL

Tags: sql

I accidentally updated a column off all rows of my table. Now I'm wondering if there's a SQL query to undo or go back before executing the update?

Comment: Is the UPDATE commited? If it is, kindly ask the DBA to restore!

Comment: rollback.......

Comment: Yes it's committed!!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I'm using sql-server